# Cakephp model only read default MySQL schema -> model was not found in datasource default

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a MySQL database with two schemas, the default one and other called rabbit_db. When I try to access the model it throws the following exception:

*Table rabbit_db.api_promos for model Promo was not found in datasource default.*

When I create the same table inside the default schema it is working fine.

This is my model:

```
class Promo extends BaseModel {
  public $useTable = 'rabbit_db.api_promos';
  public $name = 'Promo';
}
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to change your default datasource or add another one in `/app/Config/database.php`.

[Here is the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html) on setting up datasources (assuming you are using CakePHP 2.x).

And [here is an example](http://programming-tips.in/cakephp-configure-multiple-databases/) showing how to specify which datasource the model should use.

The important part in that example (after defining the 2nd datasource in database.php) is to set the variable `$useDbConfig` inside your model so it knows which datasource to use. In your case it might look like this:

```
class Promo extends BaseModel {
  public $useTable = 'rabbit_db.api_promos';
  public $name = 'Promo';
  public $useDbConfig = 'rabbit_db';
}
```